# Do the commit ids remain same after a merge?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge

My team uses git and Bitbucket for version control.

I had previously created a Pull Request from one of the branches of my repository to one of the branches of the team's main repository.

This pull request was accepted and my branch was merged in.

Yesterday I added some changes to the same branch in my repository. When I tried to create a pull request to the same branch on team's repository, I was notified of some merge conflicts.

I viewed the commit log of the team's branch and realized that although the commit message, author(me) & date were same, the commit id was different in the remote branch.

What could be the problem here?

I was under the impression that even after merge commit ids are preserved.

Could something else be causing this?

P.S.
I have read that `cherry-pick` can change commit ids. Any thoughts?

Comment: I meet the similar situation. Did you find out the solution to avoid unnecessary merging?

Answer (score 9):

Merges neither preserve, nor fail to preserve, commit-IDs.  Merges make *new* commits (assuming you do them in such a way as to avoid a "fast forward" operation, anyway).

That is, given a sequence of individual commits that I will label with single letters:

```
A - B - C
      \
        D
```

commit `C` (which might perhaps really be ID `6da748a...`) has commit `B` its parent, and commit `D` (perhaps actually `740c281...`) also has commit `B` as its parent.  To merge these two commits, git must create a new commit with *two* parents:

```
A - B - C - M
      \   /
        D
```

This new commit `M` has a different ID from every other commit, but commit `D` is completely unchanged and therefore still has its same ID (`740c281...`).

Many people try to avoid making this kind of relatively-trivial merge.  Instead of taking their work (commit `C`) and your work (commit `D`) and making a new merge commit, they make a copy of your commit message—including author and date—and make the same changes to `C` that you made to `B`.  This operation is indeed called "cherry picking" (and also "rebasing"), but it makes a new, different commit, which we might call `D'`, with a new, different commit-ID:

```
A - B - C - D'
```

The most obvious difference between your original `D` and this new `D'` is that `D'` has commit `C` as its parent, rather than commit `B`.  (It also has different tree contents, in normal cases, since your `B`-to-`D` changes were applied to files as seen in version `C`, which are likely different in some places from those in `B`.)

Commit `D'` is not a *merge* commit, however.  (A merge commit is any commit with at least two parent commits.  Use `git log --graph` or `gitk` or some other graphical viewer to see the commit graph more directly.)

If your work is rebased (or cherry-picked) into an upstream, and you fetch and then attempt to merge the upstream, git will sometimes, but not always, be able to detect the duplication and clean up automatically.  When it cannot auto-detect the duplication, you will almost always get various merge conflicts: git sees you trying to change some code (in your commit `D` in the above example), and them trying to change the same code, but in a slightly different way (in their commit `D'` in the above).  For this reason, it's generally not considered very polite to rebase someone else's code: instead, upstreams tend to ask you to rebase your code yourself (while it's still private to you) and then they can include it as a "fast forward" (merge-free) addition to their repository.

(This way you can also make any changes required by the rebase operation yourself.  For instance, if you fixed a bug in your version `D` that they also fixed in their `C`, but you and they took different approaches, you can resolve this conflict—possibly more easily than they can since you know what you did and why you did it that way, and whether your new feature depends on *your* version of the fix.)

Comment: You mention
"To merge these two commits, git must create a new commit with two parents". My question. If in the merge, one file does not change, I think the file's commit ID history will not add this merge commit ID.

Comment: I don't understand the comment.  A merge commit ID is a crypographic checksum of the merge's contents.  The merge's contents are the same as any other commit object, except for the fact that there are multiple `parent` entries, one for each parent commit.  File (i.e., blob) IDs are relevant only in that the parent IDs checksum the tree IDs of their trees, which checksum the IDs of all sub-trees and blobs.  Note that this is a sum of the *contents*; deltas are irrelevant here; in this particular respect, git is not storing deltas and does not care about diffs.

Comment: Sorry, I should restate my question. If in the merge, one file does not change, which means they should point to the same blob.

Comment: If the merge action makes no changes to some file, the blob will indeed have the same SHA1.  If the merge makes no changes to any file in a directory, the tree will have the same SHA1 as well.  A merge that makes no changes at all to the top level will therefore have the same top-level tree ID as one or more of its parent commits.  But it's still a new *commit*, a new object with a new ID, containing two or more parent IDs, a tree ID, an author and committer, and a log message.  (If you're wondering how you go from blob ID to trees to commits, it's difficult!  You must walk the entire DAG.)

Comment: If they point to the same file blog, why did you say "git will sometimes, but not always, be able to detect the duplication and clean up automatically. When it cannot auto-detect the duplication"? Should the git always be able to detect duplication and not issue conflicting issues?

Comment: The earlier comments were talking about files that have no modifications.  In this case the merge is easy.  The problem occurs when there are files that *do* have modifications.  The scenario described above can be summarized as: "I change three lines and commit, and I give you my change.  You decide to alter my change to change three DIFFERENT lines; you commit that instead of using my commit.  Now I ask git to merge my commit and your commit."  We both have changes.  So this is quite unrelated to the question of unchanged files.

Comment: thanks. Now I understood. I thought Git will trace the commits of files. But it is not desinged that way.