# After merge, how does the commit ID of a merged file (no conflicts) change?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

Suppose we have branch A, and branch B.

Branch A works on file a.cpp, and have several commits say commit ID 10000 10001, 10002, 10003 (faked).

Branch B has a.cpp. a.cpp still shows the old commit ID 10000. [Note] Branch B has other commits already. But a.cpp history in Gighub only show one old commit ID 10000.

Now we merge A to B.
In B, we have a.cpp. What are its history commit ID series "FOR a.cpp File"?
I didn't mean the commit history for B. I mean the history for the file a.cpp (you will see that in Gighub)

Are they same commit IDs?

I assumed they are the same. 
But from one practical project on Github, I find they are not the same!

The problem is: Someone made modification on some other files in Branch B (not on a.cpp file). Later on I merge B to A, since I work on A, I find that there are conflicts for a.cpp file, although they are the same! (but different commit IDs).

I don't want to resolve the conflicts, which is time-consuming.

[Update 1]
Here is some quote from
[Do the commit ids remain same after a merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993253/do-the-commit-ids-remain-same-after-a-merge)

> If your work is rebased (or cherry-picked) into an upstream, and you
>   fetch and then attempt to merge the upstream, git will sometimes, but
>   not always, be able to detect the duplication and clean up
>   automatically. When it cannot auto-detect the duplication, you will
>   almost always get various merge conflicts:

How come? If Git cannot automatically detect no change of some files, it creates a lot of fake merge conflict errors, which is time-consuming to manually solve.

[Update 2] 
Thanks for answers below.
However, in github, I find that different commit IDs for the same commit files, authors and change.
See the quote from [Do the commit ids remain same after a merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993253/do-the-commit-ids-remain-same-after-a-merge)

> I viewed the commit log of the team's branch and realized that
>   although the commit message, author(me) & date were same, the commit
>   id was different in the remote branch.

[Update 3]
For Tomato Branch:

1000, 1001, 1002, 1003

For Potato Branch:

1000, 2001, 2002, 2003

Now merge Tomato Branch to Potato Branch:

The common ancestor is 1000,  and the merge commit is 2004

Between 1000 and 2004, there are 1001, 1002, 1003, 2001, 2002, 2003.

it seems Git put them between based on chronicle order, AND change the commit name.
So it would like

1000

(    3001 (from 1001),

3002 (form 1002),

4001 (from 2001),

4002 (from 2002),

4003 (from 2003),

3003 (from 1003)    )

2004

Merge are based on common ancestor 1000, and the two latest commits from the two branches (1003, 2003).

Git also give out 4003, which might mean it also merge:

2003 AND 1002

So actually Git might do many merging operations in order to give out an effective chronicle intermediate commits.

Comment: merges are also commits, so you should have one extra commit in branch B

Comment: Yes, there is an extra commit in branch B.

Comment: So I guess this answers your question

Comment: Please add a link to the actual github repository and give the correct commit ids. everything else is too vague.

Comment: @michas, sorry, it is not an open github repository. Please see [Update]. You can see someone meets the same problem.

Comment: @user1914692 consider giving the output of `git log --graph --format=format:'%h'` with your own annotations so that one can at least get an idea of the structure of the tree and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Each commit always contains all files of your repository. If you change any file (and commit that change) you will get a new commit with a new commit id.

- Without any commit on B:

Before the commit your history looks like this:

```
10000, 10001, 10002, 10003
  B                    A
```

You have 4 commits. Branch B points to the first one and branch A to the last one.

After the merge it looks like this:

```
10000, 10001, 10002, 10003
                      A,B
```

Git noticed that you did not do any commits on B and therefore simply does a fast-forward. Therefore now both branches point to the same commit.

- If there was another commit on B:

Before the commit your history looks like this:

```
10000,    10001,   10002,   10003
   10004                        
     B                        A
```

Now commit 10004 was made on branch B. while branch A still points to 10003.

After the merge it looks like this:

```
10000,    10001,   10002,   10003
   10004                           10005
                             A      B
```

Now git created a real merge commit (10005) combining 10003 and 10004.
If 1004 did not change any file change by A there should be no merge conflict.

Comment: Thanks. So now there is merge conflict in the file a.cpp, which has no difference at all!

Comment: see [Update 1]. Somebody mentions that git sometimes cannot detect no merge conflict.

Comment: Use `git mergetool` to show you the conflict. If there was no change there is definitely no conflict! Asuming that both A and B really contain the same commit 10000 as you stated above. Use `git log --graph --decorate --online A...B` to verify.

Comment: Someone made modification on some other files in Branch B (not on a.cpp file). I guess git fails to detect that the a.cpp file doesn't change. Do you think it is possible, like the quote in [Update 2]

Comment: I think after merge, the intermediate commit IDs will change. Like Branch A is merged to Branch B, all commits ID in Branch A after the common ancestor will change. So there are no 10001, 10002. The reason is that 10001 would not contain 10004 whose chronicle order is earlier than 10001. So commit 10001 must has a new commit, say 40001, to merge 10001 and 10004.

Comment: Commits and their IDs **NEVER** (!) change. Thats one of the very basic concepts of git. If you are not conviced, just set up a new local test repository and check yourself. (You can, for example, use `gitk` to visualize your history.)

Answer (score 1):

To see how things work in git, sometimes I like to use [Visualizing Git Concepts with D3](http://www.wei-wang.com/ExplainGitWithD3/#) which does a reasonable job of showing how the repository looks with each commit or branch or rebase.

Starting out with:

```
git branch B
git commit
git commit
git commit
```

the repo will look like:

[image]

Checking out B (`git checkout B`) brings us to:

[image]

And now to bring the two into sync with a `git merge master`:

[image]

The history on the side looks like:

[image]

Note the fast-forward merge.  Git detected no changes were done on B since the branch so it was able to just move the label.

However, if we don't move to the B branch and instead do a `git merge B` while on master, we get:

[image]

Comment: see [Update 2]. commit ID changes for the intermediate commits

Comment: I didn't mean the commit history for B. I mean the history for the file a.cpp (you will see that in Gighub)