# Git: why can't Git detect its ancestor rather than ask to solve the conflict

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I have a Master branch and a Work branch.
I work on the Work branch, and the team will update Master branch.

Work branch:  1000 <--- 1001 <--- 1002

Master branch: 1000

Now merge Work branch into Master branch, and it is worked on.

Master branch: 1000 <--- 1001 <--- 1002 <--- 1003 <--- 1004

Work branch now want to merge Master branch to Work branch.
Suppose 1003 and 1004 commits have some changes to file a.cpp

I assume the a.cpp in Work branch will automatically updated with the latest version of a.cpp in commit 1004 from Master branch.

But git shows not!
It asks to resolve the conflicts for a.cpp.

both added: a.cpp

But I compared the a.cpp in Work branch, and a.cpp in Master branch.
a.cpp in Work branch is one of the ancestors of a.cpp in Master branch, i.e. in commit 1002.

Please advise me why and what is an easy way to solve it?

[Update 1]
Sorry, I think I overly simplify the situation.
Actually before Work branch is merged into master branch, there have been some commits in master branch.

Work branch:  1000 <--- 1001 <--- 1002

Master branch should be :  1000 <-- 2001 <-- 2002

After Work branch is merged to Master branch,

Master branch: 1000 <--- merge (1002, 2002) <--- 2003 <--- 2004

Now merge Master branch back to Work branch
I assume no conflicts for this merge.
Since the chronicle order is like: Master codes on a.cpp, Work codes on a.cpp, Master codes on a.cpp, Work get a.cpp from Master

[Update 2]
Now I understand there will be conflicts warning.
Git doesn't follow the chronicle order of files. It only follow the chronicle order of commits.

Comment: Didn't you already ask exactly this question a few hours ago? http://stackoverflow.com/q/27408639/1870481

Comment: @michas, please remove downvote. :) The previous question is about to understand the commit ID. And the problem in Updates are the situation when the two files from two branches are the same! Here one file is an ancestor of the other file. So totally different!

Comment: Your question does not make sense. A file cannot be an ancestor of another file. git only cares about commits.

Comment: But in other cases, some files are updated automatically with the latest version, rather than being asked for resolving conflicts.

Comment: If git is asking you to resolve conflicts, your description of what you've done is inaccurate.  You can't have conflicts without diverging histories, it's simply out of the question.

Comment: @michas, thank you. You are right. My question was wrong because I was thinking about chronicle order of files, which is not maintained by git at all.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you are doing essentially:

```
git checkout master
git commit -m 1000
git checkout -b work 
git commit -m 1001
git commit -m 1002
git checkout master
git merge work     #  fast-forward, no conflicts possible
git commit -m 1003 a.cpp
git commit -m 1004 a.cpp
git checkout work
git merge master   # again fast-forward, still no conflicts possible
```

After this both branches point to exactly the same commit and will contain exactly the same files.

If your situation is different please set up a small public repository on github demonstrating your situation.

Comment: sorry, I update to make the situation is what was. I over simplified the situation. And as in my previous question post, someone else met SIMILAR problem: some conflicts are not expected.

Comment: sorry your question is still very confusing an unclear. *Please* either add some commands to reproduce (like in this answer) or set up a public git repository showing your situation. simply adding more vague description really does not help.

Comment: you are right. I specify the question more clear. And now I understand it. Thanks.